# { [Error: timedout while connecting to smtp server] code: 4, smtp: undefined }

Tags: node.js, email

I am going to send mail in nodejs. So I have installed emailjs.
I have configured the script as the followings.

```
emailjs = require('emailjs');

var server = emailjs.server.connect({
        user:"my gmail address",
        password:"gmail passs word",
        host:"smtp.gmail.com",
        ssl:true,
        port: 456
      });

 server.send({
          text: "message",
          from:"LLVC <my outlook mail>",
          to:"<my outlook mail>",
          subject:"Subject"
        },
        function (err, message) {
        console.log(err || message);
    });
```

But I got  the errors

```
{ [Error: timedout while connecting to smtp server] code: 4, smtp: undefined }
```

I want to fix them.
Thanks.

Comment: Port 456 is certainly weird.

Answer (score 3):

It's port 465, not 456.

`If you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL) and port 587 (with TLS), but are still having trouble sending mail, try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL).`

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else is looking for an answer. What worked for me was setting ssl to true and tls to false. Adding smtp port didn't help. With that been said the following are valid smtp ports: 25, 465, 587, and 2525. I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Oh my god, I've been looking for this for like 2 hours. Thank you so much